# How do you fix missing crosshairs and incorrect hero portraits?

Tags: overwatch

When I'm playing Overwatch, sometimes the crosshairs will disappear, or they will show up as a large black box, or there will be hero portraits or health bars covering them when they shouldn't be. Below is an example of crosshairs being obscured:

[image]

Also, when at the hero selection screen, sometimes the hero portraits will be missing, or will display the incorrect hero, as shown below:

[image]

[image]

I'm using 2 GTX 980 graphics cards in SLI. I tried setting "Force rendering profile 2" under SLI settings for Overwatch in my NVIDIA control panel, as suggested on some forums and Reddit, but it hasn't resolved the issue.

I have my graphics settings set to **Epic** in Overwatch.

Comment: I had a similar issue which was fixed by disabling amd crossfire. Make of that what you will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried downgrading my graphics settings in Overwatch from Epic to **Ultra**, and it resolved all of the issues with the disappearing crosshairs and incorrect portraits.

So I suspect that one or more settings under Epic is what causes the issue, but I haven't experimented to pin-point which settings those are exactly.

Comment: I have problems sometimes with not being able to see any heroes for a bit once I start a match. I suspect that the graphics are a little intense for my card. I plan to upgrade it soon though.